# How to position text 5% from the right edge of the screen?

Tags: css

My HTML is like this

```
 <div class="maindiv">
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   <h1>Click Here</h1>
 </div>
```

I am trying to position `Hello World` in the center and the text `Click Here` 5% from the right edge of the screen.

Here is my CSS

```
    .maindiv {
    position: relative;
     }

   .maindiv h1:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: center;
    }

   .maindiv h1:nth-child(2) {
    right: 5%;
    }
```

I dont know why it is not working. I have set Parent's div to relative and set second child to right's 5% so it should be 5% off from the right but its still on the left

Comment: No, `position: relative;` and `right: 5%;` have to be on the _same_ element for `right` to have any effect.

Comment: Use margin-right rather then only right property.


.maindiv h1:nth-child(2) { margin-right: 5%; }

Comment: @Xufox relative positioning would cause the element to be shifted to the left, i.e. relative to itself, not to be relative to its parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rule on `.maindiv` only defines how that `div` behaves to its parent element. It has no effect on the `div`'s children.

Your rule on the second `h1` has no effect since `right` is ignored for static positioning and would move the element more to the left if you used it with `relative` positioning. You want it to not be bigger than 100% of the horizontal space, but still be affected by the parent's bounds. This is where `position: absolute` comes in. In order to make it relative to the parent, the parent needs its `relative` without any other settings, though (or anything non-static for that matter).

If you want them on the same height, I suggest `float` or `top: 0` with `position: absolute`.

---

What you might want instead:

```css
.maindiv {
  /* only as a reference for children positioning */
  position: relative;
}

.maindiv > h1 {
  /* You don't want margins to affect positioning here */
  margin: 0;
}

.maindiv h1:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
}

.maindiv h1:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <h1>Bar</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful. I set background to maindiv to pink but it looks like second h1 is not affected by the background color. Is it possible to explain why this is happening?

Comment: @craftdeer I'm not sure I can follow. Mind opening a new question or editing your existing one here?

Answer (score 3):

Use margin-right rather then only right property.

```
.maindiv h1:nth-child(2) { margin-right: 5%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Style your css like this:

```css
.maindiv {
    position: relative
}
.maindiv h1:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.maindiv h1:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
<h1>Centered</h1>
<h1>right-aligned</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `top: 50%` and `bottom: 0`? Also, won't `left: 50%` move the left side of the element rather than its center?

Comment: I'm not good with css that much. But as far i know if you use left 50% it will make the element center no matter what tag it is. And i used top 50% because i thought he want to horizontally center the element.

Comment: I've made your CSS runnable so you can see how it actually works (or not).

Comment: It seems like my answer is wrong. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

When positioning elements with `right`, `left`, `top`, and `bottom`, imagine the element being pushed in the direction you specify. i.e. `right:5%;` would push the element 5% to the right.

In this case, all you need to do is initially align `.maindiv` to `text-align:right`. like so:

```css
.maindiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

.maindiv h1:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
}

.maindiv h1:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
<h1>centered</h1>
<h1>right aligned</h1>
</div>
```

Your code will now work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to use multiple `<h1>` tags in one html page. So I changed the click here to `<a>` since it seems like a link by text. In the below code, click here is placed relative to `<h1>`, so if you are moving html down words, click here will also move with it. Just try this.

```css
.maindiv h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.maindiv h1 a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
   <h1>Hello World
    <a href="#">Click Here</a>
   </h1>
 </div>
```